# couldn't get output from Netmiko Script

Tags: python-3.7

**I am a little bit new in python programing i have a task to get info from a lot of Cisco Devices , According to the below Script i am trying to SSH or telnet to the devices but i cannot get any code output , i have testing the code with file containing 4 IP addresses only.
Seems there is a problem in accessing the devices**

```
from netmiko import ConnectHandler
import telnetlib
import os

cwd = os.getcwd()  # Get the current working directory (cwd)
files = os.listdir(cwd)  # Get all the files in that directory
print("Files in %r: %s" % (cwd, files))

with open ('/home/user1/Ahmed_Yousry/telnet_ip.txt') as f:
    Devices= f.read().splitlines()

username=[]
password=[]

for device in Devices:
    print('connecting to device ' + device)
    IP_Address_of_device= device
    HOST = device
####### Try Different Username and Password
    try:
        username="xxx"
        password="xxx"
    except:
        try:
            username="xxx"
            password="xxx"
        except:
            try:
                username="xxx"
                password="xxx"
            except:
                try:
                    username="xxx"
                    password="xxx"
                except:
                    try:
                        username="xxx"
                        password="xxx"
                    except:
                        try:
                            username="xxx"
                            password="xxx"
                        except:
                            try:
                                username="xxx"
                                password="xxx"
                            except:
                                try:
                                    username="xxx"
                                    password="xxx"
                                except:
                                    try:
                                        username="xxx"
                                        password="xxx"
                                    except:
                                        try:
                                            username="xxx"
                                            passwo="xxx"
                                        except:
                                            try:
                                                username="xxx"
                                                password="xxx"
                                            except:
                                                print('Unable to connect!' + device)
                                            continue

    try:
#### Connection to ssh
        IOS_device= {
                     'device_type':'cisco_ios_ssh',
                     'host':IP_Address_of_device,
                     'username':username,
                     'password':password,
                     'global_delay_factor':30}
        net_connect = ConnectHandler(**IOS_device)
        output = net_connect.send_command('show run | i username','show privilege')
        Hostname= net_connect.send_command ('show run | i hostname')
        security_Check= print ('output' + 'Hostname')
    except:
            try:
###### Connection to telnet
                    tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)
                    tn.read_until("username: ")
                    tn.write(username + "\n")
                    if password:
                        tn.read_until("Password: ")
                        tn.write(password + "\n")
                    tn.write(b"show run | i hostname\n")
                    tn.write(b"show run | i username\n")
                    tn.write(b"show privilege\n")
                    security_Check= tn.read_all()
            except:
                    print('Unable to telnet or ssh ')
            continue
    file = open ("security_Check.txt", 'w')
    file.write (str(security_Check))
    file.close ()
```

** code Output :**

connecting to device x.x.x.x
*Unable to telnet or ssh*
connecting to device x.x.x.x
*Unable to telnet or ssh*
connecting to device x.x.x.x
*Unable to telnet or ssh*
connecting to device x.x.x.x
*Unable to telnet or ssh*